# Mapping reductions for dummies

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions

I am having trouble understanding a mapping reduction and I would appreciate your help. Define

$\quad \begin{align}
  A_{TM} &= \{ \langle M, w \rangle \mid M \text{ Turing machine}, w \in \mathcal{L}(M)\} \\
  S_{TM} &= \{ \langle M,w \rangle \mid M \text{ Turing machine}, w \in \mathcal{L}(M) \implies w^R \in \mathcal{L}(M)\} \\
\end{align}$

and consider the reduction of $A_{TM}$ to $S_{TM}$ as follows.

Given $\langle M, w \rangle$ the following Turing machine $M'$ is defined:

```
M' on input x:  
  if x = 01 then accept  
  else run M on w and accept x if M accepts w
```

I don't understand the reduction entirely, this reduction is supposed to solve $S_{TM}$ using $A_{TM}$.  Why do I need to check if `x = 01`? There is no need to check anything about the reverse of $w$?  How is that covered by the reduction?

Comment: Observe that $S_{TM}$ accepts $w$ if _and only if_ it accepts $w^R$.

Comment: can you explain further? I'm not getting the hierarchy here, M gets a w, if M accepts it, why should M' get x? x is not the reverse of w.

Comment: Just a typo: if the reduction is from $A_{TM}$ to $S_{TM}$ then it "is supposed to solve $A_{TM}$ using $S_{TM}$".

Comment: Do you understand what $S_{TM}$ _is_?  That it accepts a _machine_ if and only if that machine halts on $w$ if and only if it halts on $w^R$?  Furthermore, as Vor says, you are to prove that $A \leq_m S$, i.e. that you can solve $A$ by using $S$.

Comment: What is $A_{TM}$? Where did you get this from?

Comment: $A_{TM} = { < M> |M is a TM that accepts w} . Ok, so the goal is to create a M' that solves A_tm using S_tm. so in the solution in the my original post the given <M,w> is a machine out of S_tm ?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the reduction you give in your question is the following:

I) If $\langle M,w\rangle \in A_{tm}$, then $L(M')=\Sigma^*$.
II) If $\langle M,w\rangle \notin A_{tm}$, then $L(M')=\{10\}$.

thus, for any $w$, $\langle M,w\rangle \in A_{tm}$ **iff** $\langle M',w\rangle \in S_{tm}$.
In case (I), for any $w\in L(M')$ also $w^R\in L(M')$ hence $\langle M',w \rangle S_{TM}$ for any $w$. For case (II), there is no $w\in L(M')$ such that $w^R\in L(M')$ as well, thus for any $w$, $\langle M',w \rangle S_{TM}$.

Now for your question about accepting "10" no matter what: Assume we avoid this step. Then, in case (II), $L(M')=\emptyset$, hence $\langle M',w\rangle \in S_{tm}$ for **any** $w$, since the condition on $w,w^R$ vacuously holds. Now the mapping cannot map inputs  $\langle M,w\rangle \notin A_{tm}$ to inputs outside $S_{TM}$ (since none exists).

The value "10" is arbitrary. Any other non-palindromic string will do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible reduction for $A_{tm} \le S_{tm}$.

Map input $\langle M,w\rangle$ to $\langle M', 0w1\rangle$ such that

> $M'$ on input $x$:
>   0. if $x$ can be written as $1x'0$ for some $x'$, accept. Otherwise,
>   1. if $x$ can be written as $0x'1$ for some $x'$, run $M$ on $x'$ and output the same.
>   2. Otherwise, accept (or reject, it doesn't matter).

*proof.*
If $\langle M,w\rangle \in A_{TM}$ then $M$ accepts $w$. Observe that $M'$ accepts both $0w1$ (rule 1) and $1w^r0$ (rule 0), thus $\langle M', 0w1\rangle \in S_{TM}$.
On the other hand, if $\langle M,w\rangle \notin A_{TM}$, then also $M'$ doesn't accept $0w1$, and $\langle M', 0w1\rangle \notin S_{TM}$.

Observe that both $A_{TM}$ and $S_{TM}$ are $RE$ languages (which are not in $R$).
You can also prove a reduction $S_{TM} \le A_{TM}$, by mapping $\langle M,w\rangle$ to $\langle M',w\rangle$, with $M'$ that runs $M$ on $w$ and then on $w'$. The proof is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Ran has a good short answer, so I'll do a semi-formal proof for this based on the provided $M'$:
The goal of a mapping reduction is to show that for some function F  \begin{equation} \forall x \in \Sigma^*, x \in A_{TM} \Longleftrightarrow F(x) \in S_{TM} \end{equation}
In other words, every x (encodings of M with a string w) in $A_{TM}$ has to be in $S_{TM}$ and every x that is not in $A_{TM}$ must not be in $S_{TM}$
Case 1: $ \langle M,w\rangle  \in A_{TM} \implies \langle M'\rangle \in S_{TM} $
$\quad$ $M'$ will accept x if it is 01 of course. For anything that is not 01, it will
$\quad$ proceed to run $M$ on it, and since we're assuming that $\langle M,w\rangle \in A_{TM}$,
$\quad$ every other x will also be accepted by $M'$. Therefore, $L(M') = \Sigma^*$
$\quad$ which implies that every word $w$ has a $w^R$ in it, meaning that $
\langle M'\rangle \in S_{TM}$.

Case 2: $\langle M,w\rangle \notin A_{TM} \implies \langle M'\rangle \notin S_{TM}$
$\quad$ Case 2.1: $\langle M,w\rangle$ fails the input typecheck (assuming we have one) so we output a $const_{out}$ which is
$\quad \quad$ guaranteed to not be in $S_{TM}$.
​
$ \quad$ Case 2.2: $M$ halts and rejects on $w$
$\quad \quad$ We always accept 01 since that is given. But now when we run $M$ on any input x that is not 01, we will
$\quad \quad$ reject that x since $w$ is not in $M$. Therefore, $L(M') = \{01\}$
$\quad \quad$ which is not in $S_{TM}$ since the reverse word, 10, is not present in $L(M')$.
$\quad$ Case 2.3: $M$ loops on $w$
$\quad \quad$ Same idea as when it halts and rejects, since $w \notin M$ we only have the word 01 ever begin accepted
$\quad \quad$ and so $\langle M'\rangle$ will not be in $S_{TM}$
(We can also conclude this now!). Since we've shown that we can decide $S_{TM}$, we can also decide $A_{TM}$ since we can map any input of $A_{TM}$ to $S_{TM}$. But this is a contradiction since $A_{TM}$ is undecidable. Therefore, $S_{TM}$ is undecidable as well.

Comment: Clearly, $A_{TM}\neq S_{TM}$. I don't see how the first 3 lines of your answer make sense...

Comment: Very true, to be clear this is what the mapping function is supposed to do. They definitely are not equal

Comment: Then you probably forgot $f(x)$ in the first equation, since it is logically equivalent to $A_{TM}=S_{TM}$. You might have meant: $\forall x\in\Sigma^*: x\in A_{TM}\iff f(x)\in S_{TM}$

Comment: Edited it, thanks